# What kind of constructor is this, beginning with <T extends Drawable & DrawerToggle>?

Tags: java, android, constructor

```
<T extends Drawable & DrawerToggle> ActionBarDrawerToggle(
        Activity activity, 
        Toolbar toolbar,
        DrawerLayout drawerLayout, 
        T slider,
        @StringRes int openDrawerContentDescRes,
        @StringRes int closeDrawerContentDescRes) {
```

During browsing source code of the class [ActionBarDrawerToggle.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.2_r1/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.java), I've found this constructor is declared without access specifier. Rather, its declaration starts with

```
<T extends Drawable & DrawerToggle>
```

Please explain, what does it really mean?

Comment: where do you see that code? can we see it somewhere online?

Comment: "without access specifier" specifies that it has package-private visibility. In other words, unless you're developing code in the same package, you don't really need to know this exists.

Comment: It is a method type parameter. This might help you. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/boundedTypeParams.html It is not related to whether the constructor is declared `public` or not (but instead, as @AndyTurner mentioned, package-private, which is a kind of "default" access modifier as well).

Comment: @Stultuske You can just `Ctrl+Click` and browse in Android Studio once you downloaded the source code, but I have edited and linked source url as well.

Comment: @VikasPatidar : Please avoid pasting images for code, rather simply paste the code itself, it's easier to copy/edit/...

Comment: the summary of what i understood from below answers is **<T extends A>** acts like a reference for all parameters that use **T** . so you can have 10 parameters of T without specifying *<T ex....>* 10 times

Comment: Look [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Java_Object_Oriented_Design/0370__Java_Generic_Methods_Constructors.htm) and search for "Generic Constructor"

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`T` is generic type declaration which is then used as a type for one of the arguments - `slider`.

`<T extends Drawable & DrawerToggle >` specifically means that `T` must extend/implement both `Drawable` and `DrawerToggle` classes/interfaces.

The access specifier is not mandatory. In case it's missing it means the class/method is accessible only from classes within the same package.

Comment: which doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: he's not really asking what a Generic is, he 's aware of that, but being that it's a constructor, he doesn't understand the syntax.

Comment: for a method, yes. for a constructor, no.

Comment: @Stultuske : I don't understand this. There is no difference for generics definitions in methods and constructors.

Comment: @ZbynekVyskovsky-kvr000 from what i understand method generics determines either the parameters or return type. what does generics in a constructor do ?

Comment: @SrinathGanesh : In constructor they may define only constructor parameters types. This is obvious as constructor doesn't have any return type.

Comment: @ZbynekVyskovsky-kvr000 ok so that way *<T extends B> A(Object obj)* .. wont work for *new A(new Object())* ?

Comment: @ZbynekVyskovsky-kvr000 oh ya i understood now . its nice , i should have tried out *A(T t)*

Answer (score 8):

Like normal methods, constructors can take type parameters. This is mentioned in this section of the Java Language Specification:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8

From the syntax mentioned there, you can have type parameters in the signature:

> *`TypeParameters:`*
>
> > < *`TypeParameterList`* >
>
> *`TypeParameterList:`*
>
> > *`TypeParameter {, TypeParameter}`*

and where TypeParameter is specified as

> *`TypeParameter:`*
>
> > *`{TypeParameterModifier} Identifier [TypeBound]`*
>
> *`TypeParameterModifier:`*
>
> > *`Annotation`*
>
> *`TypeBound:`*
>
> > `extends` *`TypeVariable`*
> >
> > `extends` *`ClassOrInterfaceType {AdditionalBound}`*
>
> *`AdditionalBound:`*
>
> > `&` *`InterfaceType`*

Answer (score 3):

This block specifies `slider` parameters type (value of slider parameter must extends drawable and drawabletoggle classes (or interfaces)). Search generics for more info.